# $\sigma$-algebra Generation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

(This question arises from the proof of part (b) of theorem 1.12 in Real and Complex Analysis by Rudin).

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{B}$ is that generated by $\tau$, which is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets. Let $\Omega$ be another $\sigma$-algebra such that $\tau \subset \Omega$. Rudin makes the statement that $\mathscr{B} \subset \Omega$, which is intuitive, but it isn't directly proven in the book. How can you show that this is true?

Comment: I assume you mean $\tau \subset \Omega$, not $\tau \in \Omega$. The argument is simple: if $\tau \subset \Omega$, then $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\tau$, whereas $\mathscr B$ is the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\tau$ (i.e. it is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras which contain $\tau$), so we must have $\mathscr B \subset \Omega$.

Comment: @Bungo Right! The smallest algebra is generated by taking an intersection in the proof of theorem 1.10.

Comment: If you defined the Borel algebra to be "the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets" and you now have a $\Omega$ containing the open sets, it seems like you already have $\mathscr B \subseteq \Omega$ by definition.

Comment: @MiloBrandt This isn't obvious to me. I couldn't find an easy to show that any member of $\mathscr{B}$ must be in $\Omega$. I thought that needed to be shown since this is not technically a requirement for $\mathscr{B}$ to be "smallest"...

Comment: I don't have Rudin with me, but didn't you say that Theorem 1.10 gives you the characterization that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a collection of subsets is equal to the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras which contain that collection? Thus $\mathscr B$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\tau$, and $\Omega$ is one of those $\sigma$-algebras. So, if $A$ is some member of $\mathscr B$, then $A$ is in every $\sigma$-algebra containing $\tau$, and in particular, $A$ is in $\Omega$.